# Regex - translate "a" to "zzzz" ranges to code. Only sed or grep

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

Using **ONLY** the commands: echo, grep, sed

Argument `$1` of the script is a code that has to be translated according to the table below and the translation sent to STDOUT. The code is a one to four digit code that starts in "A" and increments alphabetically to "ZZZZ". For example: A, B, .... Z, AA, AB,.....

Code - Translation

```
 - A -> 1
 - B to AA -> 2
 - AB to AF -> 3
 - AG to ZZZZ -> 4
```

For example if the script is called `script.sh` A the output would be 1. If the script is called `script.sh ABC` the output would be 4.

Comment: Did your homework assignment specifically say you have to use a regex for this?

Comment: Yes. It was a regex specific exercise. You can't use if either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1 | grep -e '^A$'>/dev/null &&  echo 1 && exit
echo $1 | grep -e '^[^A]$' -e '^[A][A]$' >/dev/null  &&  echo 2 && exit
echo $1 | grep -e '^[A][B-F]$' >/dev/null  &&  echo 3 && exit
echo $1 | grep -e '^[A-Z]\{2,4\}$'  >/dev/null  &&  echo 4 && exit
echo 0
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

str=$1

if [[ -z "${str#A}" ]]
then
  echo 1
elif [[ -z "${str#?}" || -z "${str#AA}" ]]
then
  echo 2
elif [[ -z "${str/A[B-F]/}" ]]
then
  echo 3
else
  echo 4
fi

# just in case, so you can say you used them:
grep . < /dev/null | sed > /dev/null
```

**EDIT:** silly `.`, you should be `?`.

**EDIT2:** Command `[` is gone, non-command `[[` to the rescue!

Comment: That uses the command `[`. Of course, it's not *your* homework.

Comment: @rici: You are correct, of course. Changed to `[[`.

Comment: need add one more option, exclude small letter or other digital number, for example.

Comment: @BMW: I took this to be the contract: 'The code is a one to four digit code that starts in "A" and increments alphabetically to "ZZZZ"'.

Comment: You have to use regex. Sed, grep, echo and wc only. Not even if.

Comment: `if` is a `bash` statement, not a command. Also, `grep` and `wc` won't help you if you can't use `if` or `&&` (which is equivalent to `if`). And unfortunately, `sed` is a bit problematic because of [lack of standard](http://superuser.com/questions/111996/use-of-alternation-in-seds-regex), so I don't like to use it (and you didn't specify which version of `sed` you were using).